# Why is the common base current gain giving me 0.01?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, gain

[image]

[image]

[image]

To calculate the current gain I did:

\$Gain\, of\, current=\frac{I_{out}}{I_{in}}=\frac{3,96\times 10^{-5}}{3,548\times 10^{-3}}=0,01\$

Is it normal to give a current gain, so low? What did I do wrong?

Comment: But Iout is the current through R4 resistor only.

Comment: @G36 In your calculations of the another post, why do you consider that: Io=Av/R4?

Comment: Because the current gain is Iout/Iin and Iout is R4 resistor current.

Comment: You cannot calculate current gain forcing on output with Vx to probe output impedance. Or, better, current gain you get is **reverse** current gain

Comment: @G36 I understand. But you can applied the formula Io=Av/R4, because Av=Vo/Vi and Vi=1. And you approximate Rout to R4. If If I do not want to approach, I use Io=Av/Rout, Rout=4690,62\$\,\Omega\$, right?

Comment: I dont know what you did wrong, if anything, I havent looked at your work yet. A few others do seem to concur with one another about an error you made.  That said, to comment on your final question, it is normal for current gain to be small. Perhaps not that small, but small.  You are significantly under-unity. Its normal for CB to have Ai of about 1. Its not always the case but in my experience Ai is usually smaller than Av.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum What are the units for current gain and voltage gain?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález As those terms are very commonly used, they are of course unitless. You yourself show "gain of current" and then divide a current by a current (which is unitless, as the units cancel.)

Comment: @jonk Can you tell me how much the gain of the circuit, in tension, when doing the simulation? I simulated but I do not know if I'm doing well. I would like to know the value to confirm.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález No. I'm not prepared to take the time, right now. It was easy to answer the units question, is all.

Comment: @G36 Can you tell me how much the gain of the circuit, in tension, when doing the simulation? I simulated but I do not know if I'm doing well. I would like to know the value to confirm.

Comment: @carloc Can you tell me how much the gain of the circuit, in tension, when doing the simulation? I simulated but I do not know if I'm doing well. I would like to know the value to confirm.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Can you tell me how much the gain of the circuit, in tension, when doing the simulation? I simulated but I do not know if I'm doing well. I would like to know the value to confirm.